# How to clear Microsoft Forms data after submission?

Tags: microsoft-forms

Our enterprise has adopted Microsoft Forms as a means of quickly collecting requests from various teams.

However, after a user has submitted the form, even if they open the form again days later, all of their previous entries are already pre-filled.

The only workaround I have found is to tell users to clear their cache and cookies and then reload the form. Obviously, this creates a very poor user experience.

Is there a setting within Forms that I am missing somewhere that corrects this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting in Forms that does exactly what you described.

To improve the user experience, however, you could tell the users to use an incognito window which is a much more user-friendly way to fill out the form without cache.

Comment: That would be fine if my organization didn't also use single sign-on that doesn't work in Incognito windows. Ugh. Gotta love how Microsoft purchases broken products, sells them and then abandons them.